# Count of records by Date with custom date range in mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate

I want to get all data count by date while passing custom date range in descending order . This is my code

```
  var start = new Date(req.body.from_date);  // 2018-12-03
  start.setHours(0,0,0,0);

  var end = new Date(req.body.to_date);  // 2018-12-03
  end.setHours(23,59,59,999);

db.companies.aggregate([{
  $match: {
   $and : [
    {startDate: {$gte:start} }, 
    {endDate: {$lte:end} }
   ]
  },
 },
 {
  $group:{
    _id:{ startDate:"$startDate",endDate:"$endDate",
       day: { $dayOfMonth: "$entry_date" },
       month: { $month: "$entry_date" }, 
       year: { $year: "$entry_date" }
     }, 
     count: { $sum:1 },
     date: { $first: "$entry_date" }
   }
 },
 {
    $sort:{ entry_date: -1 }
 }
 {
  $project:{
   date:{
    $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$date" }
   },
   count: 1,
   _id: 0
  }
 }])
```

if I didn't pass $match condition then it will display data count with date, but when I try to pass and condition its not working. Any idea ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I fixed it.. Thanks for support

Answer (score 0):

Dates are wrapped in the ISODate() helper function that is built into MongoDb, and is a convenient way to represent a date as a string visually, whilst still allowing the full use of date queries and indexing.

Try this:

```
$and : [
    {startDate: {$gte: ISODate("2018-11-10T18:30:00.000Z")} }, 
    {endDate: {$lte: ISODate("2018-11-30T18:29:59.999Z")} }
   ]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @Baozi, Thanks for your kind reply I tried with same, but getting " ReferenceError: ISODate is not defined " so I changed the code see the code in question again... any another solution ?

Comment: @RiteshDoomra can you supply a sample document that you are executing this code against?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, $project needs that all field which we are required in $match condition, just like I want result for date range, my field is entry_date

here is my code...

```
  var company_id= company._id 
  var start = new Date(req.body.from_date);
  start.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  var end = new Date(req.body.to_date);
  end.setHours(23,59,59,999);

VisitorCompany.aggregate(
      [   
        {
          $match: {
            $and:[
              { entry_date: { $gt: start, $lt: end } },{company_id:""+company_id+""}
            ]
          }
        },
        { $sort : { entry_date : -1 } },
          {
              $group:
              {
                  _id:
                  {
                      day: { $dayOfMonth: "$entry_date" },
                      month: { $month: "$entry_date" }, 
                      year: { $year: "$entry_date" }
                  }, 
                  count: { $sum:1 },
                  entry_date: { $first: "$entry_date" }
              }
          },
          {
              $project:
              {
                  entry_date:
                  {
                      $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$entry_date" }
                  },
                  count: 1,
                  _id: 0
              }
          }
      ])
```

and output is here....

```
    {
        "count": 1,
        "entry_date": "2018-11-18"
    },
    {
        "count": 2,
        "entry_date": "2018-11-22"
    },
    {
        "count": 2,
        "entry_date": "2018-11-23"
    },
```